# Android Change Music folder path From Sd Card to Raw File

Tags: java, android, uri, raw

i want to change music path . i have offline music player. Music player read SdCard but i want change music path and using raw folder. Thank you

```
public void getMusic() {
    Uri songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor songCursor = contentResolver.query(songUri, null, null, null, null);
    if (songCursor != null && songCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int songTitle = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int songArtist = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int songPath = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

        do {
            songsList.add(new SongsList(songCursor.getString(songTitle), songCursor.getString(songArtist), songCursor.getString(songPath)));
        } while (songCursor.moveToNext());
        songCursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont see an sd card. I dont see a music path. I dont see a raw folder.

Comment: Uri songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI; its sc card path